# jQuery can't find element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select the input element but it doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<section id="c1">
    <div class="input-group col-lg-2">
        <span class="input-group-addon">   
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>   
        </span>
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">   
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">GPS</button>   
        </span>
    </div>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#c1").find("input");
```

I'm trying to select this:

```
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: [Works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/x6aph2kw/). Did you use `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Sorry mistyped the example.

Comment: It is working. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/x6aph2kw/1/

Comment: What is the result for `$("[id='c1']").length` in your page?

Comment: Can you show the full javascript section ? It's working otherwise : https://jsfiddle.net/0n03ajzv/1/

Comment: I was trying to alert the html using '.html()' which returned blank, hence why I thought it was broken. Is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: `<input>`'s don't have inner html. I'd suggest using your console instead, or looking at the `.length` property.

Comment: If you're looking to get the value inside the input, you would use `val()`. So: `$("#C1").find("input").val();` would work for this

Comment: I think he looks to get the html of that element. See http://aghoshb.com/articles/jquery-getting-a-selected-elements-outer-html.html

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me :

When I use this HTML...

```
<section id="c1">
    <div class="input-group col-lg-2">
        <span class="input-group-addon">   
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>   
        </span>
        <input type="text" readonly class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">   
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">GPS</button>   
        </span>
    </div>
</section>
```

... and this JS...

```
var $InputElement = $("#c1").find("input");
console.log($InputElement);
```

... the console returns precisely the input element you're looking for.

Well, actually, it returns a jQuery object that contains the element you're looking for.

---

If you want the [**DOM element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) itself instead of a jQuery object, just do this :

```
var InputElement = $("#c1").find("input")[0];
console.log(InputElement);
```

---

You can try it yourself in [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v3buk7be/2/).